# Open a CBZ/CBR file in IOS

Tags: ios

I am looking to integrate opening/viewing CBZ/CBR file in iOS6 (A simple viewer like UIWebView that reads PDF file will be fine as well).

Are are there any libraries (Commercial or free) that are available for opening these file types?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CBR files are renamed .rar files and CBZ files are renamed .zip files, so you can look for a solution from there. I've never come across a library file specifically targeted for them, but that might not exclude the possibility of one existing, but as they're just standard compression files renamed to make them more portable between CBR/CBZ readers you should be okay with standard decompression libraries.

The library will spit out a number of image files when the decompression has finished, if you extract one with a standard decompression tool you'll see how they'll be presented.